# Airflow:Snowflake:Return rows from last query in a file

Tags: airflow, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow-2.x

Requirement: Returns all rows from the last query in the Snowflake SQL file

Issue: It's not returning all the rows , but only one row

Code

```
    def get_ids(self):
        snflk_hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id=self.snflk_conn_id)
        with closing(snflk_hook.get_conn()) as conn:
            with closing(conn.cursor(DictCursor)) as cur:
                cur.execute(self.sql)
                ids = []
                for row in cur:
                    ids.append(row)
            return mongo_ids
```

In the SQL File as

```
BEGIN
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE ABC_ID AS
SELECT
    *
FROM
    XYZ;

SELECT
    ID
FROM
    ABC_ID;
END
```

The last query should return all the ID's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to return resultse from Snowflake Scripting block using RESULTSET:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE XYZ AS 
SELECT 1 AS ID UNION ALL SELECT 2;
```

Code:

```
BEGIN
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE ABC_ID AS
  SELECT  *
  FROM  XYZ;

  LET res RESULTSET := (SELECT ID FROM ABC_ID);
  
  RETURN TABLE(res);
END
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How can we assign values from previous executed statement to insert values example ```
env = select current_database();
start_time = select current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz(9);
alter SESSION SET TIMEZONE = 'UTC';
end_time = select current_timestamp()::timestamp_ntz(9);
duration = (end_time.getTime() - start_time.getTime()) / 1000;
   
insert into proc_runtimes 
    (sf_env, app, task, start_time, end_time, duration, message)
values 
    (env, app, 'Job Start', start_time.toISOString(), end_time.toISOString(), duration, log_message]})
```

Comment: @Kar Hello. This comment should be a completely new question. Please create a such and I am sure somebody will be able to help

Comment: Ok thanks i am gonna create it , hope you can answer me